# How do you install Intel TBB on OS X?

Tags: macos, tbb

How do you properly install the open source version of Intel Thread Building Blocks (TBB) on OS X 10.6? The open source version doesn't seem to have a proper install script.

http://www.threadingbuildingblocks.org/ver.php?fid=154

Comment: Duplicate (unfortunately also without answers): http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3714598/installing-intels-tbb-3-0-framework-on-macos-10-6-snow-leopard

Answer (score 30):

I found an easy way to install it:

```
brew install tbb
```

Requires [Homebrew](https://brew.sh/), which is highly recommended for any Mac user wanting to use various open source tools.

Comment: As of Jan 15, 2013 the tbb install for brew appears broken.  There is a SHA1 mismatch which causes the install to fail.

Comment: Howdy, try `brew update` first, that fixed the SHA1 mismatch for me.

Comment: I get `Error: /usr/local/opt/tbb is not a valid keg`. That's after doing `brew update`

Answer (score 3):

There is a [tutorial](http://punchcard.wordpress.com/2009/11/18/using-intel-threading-building-blocks-in-a-c-xcode-project-under-mac-os-x/) for using TBB 2.2 on a Mac without MacPorts/Homebrew. Maybe that's of help for you!