# Installing Intel's TBB 3.0 framework on MacOS 10.6 (Snow Leopard)

Tags: frameworks, installation, intel, tbb, macos

I'm having a bit of trouble installing Intel's Threading Building Blocks (TBB) 3.0 as a framework on my MacOS system. Does anyone know a good tutorial? I've tried using MacPorts, which has TBB 2.2: it installs all the libraries I need, but I don't get a framework. Also, there doesn't seem to have any .dmg installation file on Intel's site that could provide this framework. All the download files are zipped files containing the src code or the binaries.

Any ideas?

Thanks!

Comment: Duplicate (unfortunately also without answers): http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3181468/how-do-you-install-intel-tbb-on-os-x

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a [tutorial](http://punchcard.wordpress.com/2009/11/18/using-intel-threading-building-blocks-in-a-c-xcode-project-under-mac-os-x/) for using TBB 2.2 on a Mac without MacPorts. Maybe that's of help for you!